# In Entity Framework Core 8, how could I delete childs entities and avoid concurrency exception if some delete some children?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an entity and it has a child entity. This is the parent entity:

```
MyParent
{
    long Id;
    HashSet<Child> Childs = [];
}
```

The process I follow is:

- I load the father and include all the children
- I clear the child collection to mark them as deleted.
- I remove the father entity from the `dbSet` collection to mark it as delete.
- I save the changes.

This works if I there is no other process that deletes one or more children.

The problem is, for example, a father with one child, before first process saves the changes, another process delete the child. In this case, I get a concurrency exception.

How could I avoid to get the exception and delete the father with all the children? Because if I want to delete the children, no matter if it is the first process or the second which deletes the child, the final result is the same for both processes, delete the father and the children.

I am not using delete on cascade in the database, because I would like to do some checks before deciding to delete or not the father.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe ConcurrencyCheck attribute for the property

Comment: One child, several **children** (not "childs")

Comment: You get a concurrency exception because there's an actual conflict going on. Why did some other process modify the same graph of objects? Why did both load the same objects and try to save the same objects again? That's a *very* unusual situation. You haven't posted any code or even the entities, so it's very hard to understand what's going on from the prose

Comment: If the use case is to *only* delete graphs, not work with the objects, you should probably use SQL directly. You can use a recursive CTE to delete a root object and all its children in most databases. If you use `hierarchyid` in SQL Server you can delete all objects below a root without a CTE